# How to make Google Search change preferred language by host without changing config?

Tags: localization, google-search

For example, sometimes I want to search by a Japanese keyword and get Japanese results (Japanese websites). To do this, I go to https://www.google.co.jp and search. However, it always returns English results.

Going to `.co.jp` means I want to seach Japanese sites; why doesn’t Google follow this simple rule?

If I change the language in config to Japanese, I have to change it back later, which is inconvenient.

Any idea?

Comment: When you say "change language config", do you mean on the Google website or in your browser settings? I suspect a userscript could help you here.

Comment: @Bob  you can change default language on www.google.com . My default is English, and my local language is Chinese, so it only suggest me show result in Chinese . But I want Japanese while using `.co.jp` ...  The biggest problem is google ignore its own host suffix still show me English .

Comment: Since this is concerning the operation of a website rather than local computer software, I am voting to migrate it to [webapps.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably get around it by bookmarking the language-redirect param, `hl`. This means appending to the URL:

- If there are no other params: `?hl=languageCode`
- If there are other params: `?otherParam=foo&hl=languageCode`

For example:

- Japanese: https://www.google.co.jp/?hl=ja (or https://www.google.com/?hl=ja)
- Chinese: https://www.google.com/?hl=zh
- English: https://www.google.com/?hl=en

If you would prefer not to click on a bookmark, you can force it to redirect every time you visit the homepage on that domain with a userscript. But that is more complicated and fragile.